# Make cursor not select a text field when switch browser tabs

Tags: google-chrome, text-editing, cursor, vimium

I started using Vimium for Google Chrome and it is great.

There is only one problem: When I cycle through my open tabs and I visit a tab like facebook, the cursor goes immediately into a textbox of a chat window, stopping me from cycling through the tabs.

Is there a way to stop Chrome from automatically choosing a text field when switching to a different tab?
To make my question better understandable: I want to have no active cursor when I switch to an other tab, like if I would have clicked at some plain text for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option *Don't let pages steal the focus on load* on the Vimium options page to prevent that.  It's under advanced options (at the bottom).

(A better place to post questions about Vimium is over on [Github](https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues?q=is%3Aopen%20sort%3Aupdated-desc).)

Comment: I thought there is a solution outside Vimium, so I thought I could reach a bigger community here :)